# Can this be a Nested Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What are the names and length of the shoreline, in order of descending shoreline in the US, of the Great Lakes that have shorelines in both Canada and the US.

The table I use has three columns, `IN_COUNTRY`(where the lakes are, US or Canada), `ON_LAKE`(the name of the lake, like Lake Michigan) and `SHORELINE`(length of shoreline in each country)

I have tried the SQL listed below but I can not order it by the `SHORELINE` length in the United States. As you can see, I can now only order them by the combination of the shoreline in both countries.

```
SELECT ON_LAKE, sum(SHORELINE) AS SHORELINE
FROM SHORE
GROUP BY ON_LAKE
HAVING count(IN_COUNTRY) > 1
ORDER BY SHORELINE DESC
```

I think the nested SQL may help but has been stuck here for a while

Image:

[image]

Comment: share sample input and output

Comment: the output should be a table of two columns, ON_LAKE   SHORELINE are two columns and under ON_LAKE should be Lake Ontarion, Lake Erie and so on. Under SHORELINE should be the sum of the shorelines in both Canada and US

Comment: You can include your table, sample data, and your query in http://www.sqlfiddle.com for us to know more about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT ON_LAKE, sum(SHORELINE) AS SHORELINE
FROM SHORE
GROUP BY ON_LAKE
HAVING count(IN_COUNTRY) > 1
ORDER BY sum(CASE WHEN IN_COUNTRY='United States' THEN SHORELINE ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

I only changed the ORDER BY clause to calculate the shore length in United States.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an aggregation approach, then we can try this:

```
SELECT ON_LAKE, SUM(SHORELINE) AS SHORELINE
FROM SHORE
GROUP BY ON_LAKE
HAVING MIN(IN_COUNTRY) = 'Canada' AND MAX(IN_COUNTRY) = 'United States'
ORDER BY
    SUM(CASE WHEN IN_COUNTRY = 'United States' THEN SHORELINE ELSE 0 END) DESC;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Actually I want the shoreline column has the sum of shorelines in both country. For example, For lake superior is 1750

Comment: @OrionD Your question was unclear then about the output you wanted.

Comment: Sorry, but the output should be ordered by the length of shoreline of the lake in the US so lake superior should be in front of Lake Huron because 1000 is greater than 850

Comment: OK, I fixed it.  For next time, a good SQL question on Stack Overflow shows a) sample input data, b) the output you expect, and c) a good verbal description of the logic involved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
SELECT ON_LAKE,  sum(SHORELINE)
FROM SHORE
where IN_COUNTRY='Canada' and IN_COUNTRY='United States'
Group By ON_LAKE
ORDER BY sum(SHORELINE) DESC
```